# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'YYY.ILogDataAccess' while attempting to activate 'XXX.CustomExceptionFilter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I know there are lots of questions and information on internet over this problem. But searching 4-5 hours, I could not resolve the matter. Looking for direct or indirect help / direction.

> I am using :  VS 2017 ASP .Net Core 2.0

Say, I have 3 projects in a solution.

1. DataAccess (interact with database)
2. Logging (To log in several way)
3. Api (or service)

In my Api, there is a `CustomExceptionFilter` from `IExceptionFilter`. I am handling all exception from `OnException()`.

I need to create log inside `OnException`. And To Log, I need to access to DB.

For that purpose, in `Startup.cs`, `ConfigureServices()`, I am injecting the dependency of `CustomExceptionFilter`, as it will need LoggingWrapper in `OnException()` method.

Here is the code :

```
services.AddSingleton<IExceptionFilter>(
new CustomExceptionFilter(
new LogDataAccess(
appServiceConfig.ConnectionString, appServiceConfig.Database)));
```

Here `LogDataAccess` is the class to insert log into database.

And I have overrided a constructor in `CustomExceptionFilter` class like :

```
private ILogDataAccess logDataAccess;

public CustomExceptionFilter(ILogDataAccess logDataAccess)
{
    this.logDataAccess = logDataAccess;
}
```

Building the project is fine. While I run, `startup.cs` executes fine so far. `logDataAccess` is instantiated nicely. After completing other statements in Startup.cs, when it tries to come out from "`program.cs`"'s main entry point, 
It shows the error :

Here is the stacktrace of error.

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'DataAccess.ILogDataAccess' while attempting to activate 'QuestionService.Common.CustomExceptionFilter'.

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)

   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TypeFilterAttribute.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultFilterProvider.ProvideFilter(FilterProviderContext context, FilterItem filterItem)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultFilterProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(FilterProviderContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.FilterFactory.CreateUncachedFiltersCore(IFilterProvider[] filterProviders, ActionContext actionContext, List`1 filterItems)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.FilterFactory.GetAllFilters(IFilterProvider[] filterProviders, ActionContext actionContext)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvokerCache.GetCachedResult(ControllerContext controllerContext)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvokerProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionInvokerProviderContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionInvokerFactory.CreateInvoker(ActionContext actionContext)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcAttributeRouteHandler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<RouteAsync>b__0(HttpContext c)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

I have added `CustomExceptionFilter` in the same method `ConfigureServices()`
like this as well.

```
   services.AddMvc(
            config =>
            {
                config.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomExceptionFilter));
            }
        );
```

This is added for global exception filter.

Comment: it seems like dependency issue have you registered your `ILogDataAccess` in `ConfigureServices()` `startup.cs` ? something like `services.AddScoped<ILogDataAccess, IMPLEMENTEDCLASS>();`

Comment: What I found so far is, the error is showing because of the constructor of `CustomExceptionFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register `LogDataAccess` instead of `CustomExceptionFilter` in DI.

change:

```
services.AddSingleton<IExceptionFilter>(new CustomExceptionFilter(new LogDataAccess(
    appServiceConfig.ConnectionString, appServiceConfig.Database)));
```

to:

```
services.AddSingleton<ILogDataAccess>(new LogDataAccess(
    appServiceConfig.ConnectionString, appServiceConfig.Database));
```